# Unable to load data into a table using the LOAD DATA statement (w/ a tab delimited file)

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I'm attempting to load a tab delimited file into my dataset by the following script:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\host_table_airbnb_new.txt'
INTO TABLE host;

SHOW VARIABLES 
LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

But I'm getting an error as

> Error Code: 1290 "secure_file_priv" is on.

I believe that my syntax is correct and my file is located in the correct prescribed location, but by some reason I cannot load my data.

Could you please help me to understand what and where I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You should remember to use \\ (double backslash) in windows paths: 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\host_table_airbnb_new.txt'

Comment: the double backslash worked! thanks for the help